# Code Golf - Covfefe on tap

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity

As we all know, negative press covfefe has been conspiring to bring down the American president for some months now.

There's also, definitely, an algorithm in play in that word. Covfe is a refreshing caffeinated beverage, and following the president's remarks it's clear the word can now be appended with successive f's and e's, so long as they are not adjacent to their own letters.

So I wrote some code to generate the inevitable covfefe triangle. The output looks like this:

```
covfefe
covfefef
covfefefe
covfefefef
covfefefefe
covfefefefef
covfefefefefe
covfefefefefef
covfefefefefefe
covfefefefefefef
covfefefefefefefe
covfefefefefefefef
covfefefefefefefefe
covfefefefefefefefef
covfefefefefefefefefe
covfefefefefefefefefef
covfefefefefefefefefefe
covfefefefefefefefefefef
covfefefefefefefefefefefe
covfefefefefefefefefefefef
covfefefefefefefefefefefefe
```

So here are the rules:

- Output 21 lines, the first of which should be 'covfefe'.
- Each line must be one character longer than the previous line.
- No f can be horizontally adjacent to another f.
- No e can be horizontally adjacent to another e.

Oh, and have fun!

(I'm also interested to see any other nifty covfefe-related snippets)

Comment: Do we need to print the quoted text as is? Or, can we print any text meeting the conditions listed?

Comment: Can we return an array of strings?

Comment: The output shown has plenty of `e`s adjacent to `e`s (and same for `f`s), I suppose you meant "on a [horizontal]  line"? (or maybe you mean in the code??)

Comment: @Shaggy That goes directly against the rules in the original question, I think it's got to print them somewhere, really.

Comment: I don't understand your answer.

Comment: Just curious, why the downvotes? Anyone know?

Comment: Wait, you're suggesting others might object if I output the example text you posted?!

Comment: I think the downvotes are probably because of the lack of clarity of the question.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Ahh, sorry, I completely misread. Yes, I did mean within one line. Although I'd love to see a result which avoids vertical adjacency too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 13 bytes

```
Ｅ²¹⁺cov…fe⁺⁴ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM3sUDDyFBHISCntFhDKTm/TElHwbkyOSfVOSO/QEMpLVUJKmeio5CpCQLW////1y37r1ucAwA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
            Implicitly print joined with newlines
Ｅ²¹         the implicit range 0..21 mapped to
   ⁺cov     the concatenation of "cov" with
    …fe     the characters "fe" repeated until their length is exactly
     ⁺⁴ι    4 more than the value
```

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>17</s> 16 bytes

```
„fe12×η¦¦¦…covì»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//UcO8tFRDo8PTz20/tAwEHzUsS84vO7zm0O7//wE)

**Explanation**

```
„fe               # push the string "fe"
   12×            # repeat it 12 times
      η           # get the prefixes of this string
       ¦¦¦        # drop the first 3
          …covì   # prepend the string "cov" to each
               »  # join on newline
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>17</s> 16 bytes

```
4o25_îeif)i`¬v
```

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=NG8yNV/uZWlmKWlgrHY=&input=LVI=) 14 bytes of code, +2 for `-R` flag. If we can output as an array, simply remove the `-R` and subtract 2 bytes.

#### Explanation

```
4o25              Generate the range [4, 5, ..., 24].
    _             Map each item in this range to
      eif           "fe" (really weird hack, but it works and saves a byte)
     î   )          repeated to length <item>
          i`¬v      with "cov" inserted at the beginning.
                  Implicit: output result of last expression, joined with newlines (-R)
```

Alternatively, you could do `7o28_îfie)h"cov`, which does the same thing, except overwriting `cov` onto the beginning of the string instead of inserting it at the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 37 bytes

```python
s='covfef'
exec"s+=s[-2];print s;"*21
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v9hWPTm/LC01TZ0rtSI1WalY27Y4Wtco1rqgKDOvRKHYWknLyPD/fwA)

Matches the text  shown.

---

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 36 bytes

```python
s='covfefe'
exec"print s;s+='?';"*21
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v9hWPTm/LC01LVWdK7UiNVmpoCgzr0Sh2LpY21bdXt1aScvI8P9/AA)

Prints:

```python
covfefe
covfefe?
covfefe??
covfefe???
covfefe????
covfefe?????
covfefe??????
covfefe???????
covfefe????????
covfefe?????????
covfefe??????????
covfefe???????????
covfefe????????????
covfefe?????????????
covfefe??????????????
covfefe???????????????
covfefe????????????????
covfefe?????????????????
covfefe??????????????????
covfefe???????????????????
covfefe????????????????????
```

Comment: Nice loophole, `Each line must be one "character" longer`

Comment: `Attempt to produce this result with the fewest characters in your code.` This must clearly produce the quoted text above. I would downvote this for being against the spirit of the challenge but I know it is only tongue in cheek. It would be better if you flipped the answer order around though.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder I actually did intend this as a serious answer. The conditions like "No f can be adjacent to another f" seem to say that "this result" is anything that meets them. Otherwise I don't see why they would be listed. I guess I'll ask.

Comment: @xnor I agree it is kind of within the rules but I think it goes against the spirit of the challenge.

Answer (score 2):

### [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 29 bytes

```
Vr4 25+"cov"+*/N2"fe"?%N2"f"k
```

Explanation:

```
Vr 4 25      Loops variable N from 4 to 24 (excludes 25)
    */N2"fe"     Repeats string "fe" N / 2 number of times 
        ?%N2"f"k     Concatenates "f" if N % 2 is 1 (odd), or an empty 
                     string if it is even (N % 2 is 0) 
            +            Concatenates strings
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P6zIRMHIVFspOb9MSVtL389IKS1VyV4VRCtl//8PAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), <s>16</s> 15 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
4'⁷Ν{ņcoļvƧfemo
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=NCUyNyV1MjA3NyV1MDM5RCU3QiV1MDE0NmNvJXUwMTNDdiV1MDFBN2ZlbW8_)

Explanation:

```
4'⁷Ν             push inclusive range from 4 to 24
    {            for each do
     ņcoļv         output in a new line "cov" (split into 2 commands of "output 2 chars in a new line" and "output next char" for a byte save)
          Ƨfemo    output "fe" molded into the length of the current item
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>53</s> 52 bytes

```python
f=lambda n=21:n*' 'and'\ncovf'+('ef'*12)[:-n]+f(n-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P802JzE3KSVRIc/WyNAqT0tdQT0xL0U9Ji85vyxNXVtDPTVNXcvQSDPaSjcvVjtNI0/XUPN/QVFmXolCmobmfwA)

Answer (score 1):

Totally valid answer which matches the specs/rules.

## PowerShell, 25 Bytes. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/Xyk5vywtNS1VydpCT8/Ioka1Wt1eXUslvvb/fwA)

```
"covfefe";8..28|%{'?'*$_}
```

OR (same byte count)

```
0..21|%{'covfefe'+'?'*$_}
```

As intended answer which matches the example output.

## PowerShell, 44 Bytes. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XyXZVik5vywtNU3J2kBPz8igRrVaAyiokqytoZ6qrqOepq4ZrRKvahSrWfv/PwA)

```
$c="covfef";0..20|%{($c=$c+('e','f')[$_%2])}
```

Ugly assignment at the beginning, i'm sure there's some that can be saved here.

Comment: [36 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/30xPz8isRrVaNys/M09DKTm/TElbPS1VXcvQSDPaQE9PJT629v9/AA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Mono)](http://www.mono-project.com/), 132 bytes

```cs
using System.Linq;_=>{for(int i=0;i<21;)System.Console.WriteLine("cov"+string.Concat(new int[4+i++].Select((n,j)=>j%2<1?"f":"e")));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY5PS8QwEMXv@RQhICRUi7t4Mm1FvCqIe/AgIjE7lSnZGWyyK7L0s9d03S77TvPe/Pv5eLVh4nEbkb7k6jcm2Fhx7spHpG8rhA8uRvks9kJmxeQSerljXMsnh6TNIf5vTrr3CZkq/uzAp0a2sh4/6mbfcq@RksT62mK1XFhz/PLAFDlA@dpjgvwStPK8U0VMfWaZ2t4lTfAj8/rbTYFF8V6uIOTrWtNlZ@qmu1hWizvVqlsFyhhjh3Gmyfxz2WrahmDsKZh0MjPGC7j1geI4OIhh/AM)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), <s>20</s> 18 bytes

```
`¬vfef`
21ÆU±gJÉÃ·
```

[Test it](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=YKx2ZmVmYAoyMcZVsWdKycO3&input=)

16 bytes, if we can return an array.

```
`¬vfef`
21ÆU±gJÉ
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 17 bytes

```
⁾feẋ12“cov”;;\ṫ7Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASQA2/9qZWxsef//4oG@ZmXhuosxMuKAnGNvduKAnTs7XOG5qzdZ//8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 15 bytes

```
↑21↓7ḣ+¨¢√¨¢"fe
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HbRCPDR22TzR/uWKx9aMWhRY86ZoEopbTU//8B)

NB: `¨¢√¨` is the compressed strind `"cov"`

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 33 bytes

`V21+++"cov"*"fe"2*"fe"s/N2*\f%N2`

Try it here: http://pyth.herokuapp.com

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 27 bytes

```
covf12$*
1
ef
.
$`¶
G`.{7}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P@fKzm/LM3QSEWLy5ArNY1Lj0sl4dA2LvcEvWrz2v//AQ) Explanation:

```
covf12$*
```

Add `covf` plus 12 `1`s.

```
1
ef
```

Change each `1` to `ef`. This results in the last line of the desired output, but with an extra `f`.

```
.
$`¶
```

Replace the string with a list of all of its proper prefixes.

```
G`.{7}
```

Delete the prefixes that are too short.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>77</s> <s>75</s> 74 bytes

```c
f(i,j){for(i=4;i++<25;)for(printf("\ncov"),j=i;--j;)putchar("ef"[i-j&1]);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FccxCoUwDADQvaeQDpKgHZT/p@hJ1EGC0RSsUtRFPHvFtz12M3NKAlp6vGWLoO2PtCia@k/4fY8aDgHbB94ui6VvlZzzhPt58DJGsJPYTp3PqwHpSeuoAdDcJssEkMyTXg)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 61 bytes

```python
def f(n=20):
	print(' '*n+('covf'+'ef'*12)[:~n])
	if n:f(n-1)
```

not the shortest, but prints triangle without e/f vertical adjacency

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PyU1TSFNI8/WyEDTiouzoCgzr0RDXUFdK09bQz05vyxNXVs9NU1dy9BIM9qqLi9Wk4szM00hzwqoRddQ83@ahuZ/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 45 bytes

```perl
$_="covfef
";eval's/((.).)$/$1$2/;print;'x 20
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3lYpOb8sLTWNS8k6tSwxR71YX0NDT1NPU0VfxVDFSN@6oCgzr8RavULByOD/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 39 bytes

```perl
$b=covfef;say$b.=substr$b,-2,1for 1..21
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lyTY5vywtNc26OLFSJUnPtrg0qbikSCVJR9dIxzAtv0jBUE/PyPD//3/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9TfUMDA0A)

Answer (score 0):

**Ruby - 53 chars**

```
s='covfef';21.times{|i|puts s +=(i.odd? ? 'f' : 'e')}
```

*Note:* This is the OP's answer, there must be better one's out there.

Comment: I don't know Ruby, but something tells me that you don't need spaces around `:`.

Comment: Note: It is frowned upon to post an answer to your own challenge immediately. You should let others have a chance to answer it and wait at least a day, probably longer.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Fair point, this is my first attempt at posing a code puzzle... I'll delete it, for the time being.